# How can I access my router settings after installing Apache

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, apache-http-server

I recently installed Apache to mess around with, but after setting it up, my normal method of accessing my router settings (just typing in my ip address) makes me just go to whatever I have Apache set up as. I'm using MI424-WR Rev.D, my ISP is Verizon and I am connecting wirelessly, how can I access my router settings?

Comment: What does Apache have to do with accessing your router?

Comment: -1  I doubt typing in your comps ip ever went to your router's page. unless your browser autocompleted it into your router's ip. I suppose that is what happened. and when you installed apache, and started using your cmop's ip, it autocompleted to that. Lesson- watch what ip you are going to!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to find out what is your router's IP.

Are you using Windows? If so, type `ipconfig` on the command line, take note of the IP stated on the "gateway" line, and type it on your browser's address bar.